# No payment methods available after entering zip?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, payment-methods

**Magento 2.2.6 with standard checkout**

I have 3 available countries in my checkout. After switching between the countries, the available payment methods are shown or hidden accordingly, so that works as expected.

As soon as I enter the zip (no matter if its a correct or wrong zip) though and switch the countries, it keeps showing me the "no payment methods available" message. Is there any settings that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Enable the sql query log and check what queries are running and what are the results of those queries.

Comment: How do I enable it, or are you talking about the standard logs?

Comment: Magento writes database activity logs to the var/debug/db.log file inside the Magento application directory. Use the command php bin/magento dev:query-log:enable

Comment: Ok, thanks, Ill take a look!